# Hotkey for the "top bar" menu in the header?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I often need to use the menu in the top bar. The menu with `File`, `Edit`, `Render`, `Window`, `Help`. After clicking `File`, the File sub-menu shows up and now I can use the underlined hotkeys to select the options I need.

But how do I open the `File` menu in the first place? On Windows, the default behaviour of most programs is that you can just press `ALT` and that will focus on the top bar. Pressing `ALT+F` will open the `File` menu. But on Blender that doesn't work.

Do I have to manually click `File` with the mouse every time I need something from that menu? Is there any way I can assign a hotkey to open the `File` menu. On the Keymap preferences I've only found a "File Context Menu" (F4), but that only opens a limited version of the File menu, not the full menu, it's missing options.

Comment: You don't need to open "File", "Edit" and so to use the shortcuts, you cand just press it and should work (Example F12 = Render)

Comment: @Emir -- while that is true, many of us are keyboard oriented and from Windows we often like to peruse the menus especially while we are learning the Render is indeed F12 also.  Entering the blender world can on certain days be like taking a cold shower.

Comment: You can add it to Quick Favourites by right-clicking on it. Then use the 'Q' key and 'F' to bring up the menu. If you have Hard Ops installed you have to press 'Q' twice before the 'F'.

Comment: @JohnEason that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found 2 solutions:

1. Press F3 to open search. You can then type "file" and all the file sub-menu options will show up. You can then browse them and type any of the sub options to select them. If you already know the sub-option you want, you can directly type it on search.
2. As John Eason suggested on the comments, you can right click on any of the options in a sub-menu to either directly add a shortcut to them, or to add them as a favorite. Then just press Q to open the favorites.